# Fresco drawee view hierarchy onFailure getting called even for successful load of images from uri

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, android-library, fresco

I am trying to replace the drawee view with my own custom view when the image load from given uri fails(in which case the drawee view remains blank).
So to check if the load has failed I used

mThumbnail.getHierarchy().setFailure(new CustomThrowable(parameters));

Also in the xml I have set the fresco:failureImage.

However when I run the code the setFailure get's called regardless whether the load has failed or succeeded and the custom view is being displayed for all of them. But I see the failureImage being loaded in the background, (behind the custom layout) only at the places where it has ACTUALLY failed. I don't know why this is happening.

How do I make the setFailure get called only when load is failed.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, if you call setFailure directly, obviously setFailure will have been called.

Are you confusing `setFailure` with `setFailureImage?` setFailureImage specifies what image is to be shown on failure; that is the method meant for app developers. setFailure is called by the image pipeline when there actually is a failure. If you call it, it's a failure even if the real image pipeline did succeed.